# what is it that you can do with canvas and not with SVG?

Tags: html, svg, graphics, html5-canvas

I am working on project I need to choose between the SVG and Canvas. I am finding SVG best at most of the things.

Are there anythings that you can not do with the SVG but you can with Canvas?

Comment: X vs Y questions don't go down well here (see https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/). What are you trying to do? There are lots of things canvas is best at and lots of things SVG is best at as they are quite different (raster vs vector). The question is too broad and unfocussed in its current form.

Comment: @RobertLongson. Agreed, as stated the question is broad -- maybe too broad. Having said that I think we can pare down the broadness since SVG and Canvas have remarkable similarities and the question is asking about the few differences. So I'm going to try to post a narrowed answer to their broad question. This narrowed Q&A hopefully fits as acceptable under the "questions about software tools commonly used by programmers" topic. I'll give it a try anyway :-)

Answer (score 4):

**First,**

If you already have invested time in the SVG learning curve, you might well complete your project without Canvas because these 2 elements do remarkably similar things. Canvas has a fairly large & steep learning curve that you might want to avoid "mid-project".

**Contrary to popular opinion...Both Canvas and SVG use vector drawing commands!**

They use vector commands to paint lines and curves on their drawing surfaces. Both Canvas and SVG render those drawings onto their element surfaces as pixels.

**And...**

Both Canvas and SVG can transform (offset,  rotate and scale) their drawings. Both Canvas and SVG can apply style to their drawings (fill color, stroke color, opacity, etc).

**But...**

SVG goes one step further and "remembers" all the drawing commands. This means SVG can reissue those drawing commands even when scaling. So SVG is ideal for drawings that must be scaled without becoming "jaggy". You can even use CSS to re-style your drawings (change colors, opacity, position, rotation, etc). That's often very useful. For example, you can make an SVG leopard change the color of its spots *with CSS!*

Canvas just "draws and forgets" -- it remembers nothing about what or where it's drawn. As such, it's a lighter element. You say: "But canvas does all those games with moving players". With canvas, the programming practice is to erase the canvas and redraw any shapes in their new positions. This gives the illusion that the shapes are being commanded to move (which they are not). Canvas is built to be extremely fast at these redraws and will easily redraw modestly complex game scenes at 60 frames per second. This speed comes at the cost. You must "remember" where your scene elements are so you can later re-render them in their new positions and with their new stylings. (No simple CSS ability to make a canvas leopard change its spots).

SVG drawings come with the traditional mouse events already built in. Canvas only fires the traditional mouse events on the canvas as a whole and not on individual drawings (because canvas forgets about the shapes it's drawn). Therefore, if you want to get mouse events related to an individual canvas shape you must (1) Remember where you drew your shapes (2) listen for the mouse event on the whole canvas, (3) check if the mouse is inside any shape (this is easily done mathematically) and then handle the mouse event for your discovered shape. Canvas elements require more code to impliment.

**IMHO, one particular use-case where canvas shines:**

In addition to these functional differences, Canvas lets you examine and change any pixel on the canvas surface. In particular, this valuable pixel information lets you do some nice tasks with images:

- Recolor any part of an image at the pixel level (if you use HSL you can even recolor an image while retaining the important Lighting & Saturation so the result doesn't look like someone slapped paint on the image),
- "Knockout" the background around a person/item in an image,
- Detect and Floodfill part of an image (eg, change the color of a user-clicked flower petal from green to yellow -- just that clicked petal!),
- Do Perspective warping (e.g. wrap an image around the curve of a cup),
- Examine an image for content (eg. facial recognition),
- Answer questions about an image: Is there a car parked in this image of my parking spot?,
- Apply standard image filters (grayscale, sepia, etc)
- Apply any exotic image filter you can dream up (Sobel Edge Detection),
- Combine images. If dear Grandma Sue couldn't make it to the family reunion, just "photoshop" her into the reunion image. Don't like Cousin Phil -- just "photoshop him out,
- Play a video / Grab a frame from a video,
- Export the canvas content as a .jpg | .png image (you can even optionally crop or annotate the image and export the result as a new image),
- Many more image pixel manipulations that haven't come to mind!

Comment: That just makes me want to add that you can draw svg on your canvas and that you can insert canvas in your svg :-)

Comment: @Kaiido. Yes, exactly! Also, I bet you've noticed that the canvas path commands and SVG path commands are almost identical (except for arcs). They could be twins. So in addition to rendering completed svg content on canvas -- and visa-versa, you can also use simple cross-compiler code to input SVG drawing commands and render them as canvas drawing commands -- and visa-versa (f.ex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D). It even looks like the Working Group is subtly trying to unify the workings of SVG and Canvas.

Comment: You're talking of a SVG -> Canvas compiler, do you know about a reliable/complete/... one ? So far i only found this one : http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/ , which, while working, lacks a few features.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I can *highly recommend* Mike Swanson's AI->Canvas cross compiler which does a reliable and (almost) complete job of taking Adobe Illustrator SVG and exporting to canvas (http://blog.mikeswanson.com/ai2canvas). But in my answer I am talking about cross compiling just the SVG path commands with the Canvas path commands rather than cross compiling the full infrastructures of SVG and Canvas.

Comment: @markE, Just though of the svg's `getBBox` methods and related, do you think there will be something like this implemented for Path2d ?

Comment: @Kaiido. I suspect that directly computed mathematical methods (like getBBox) will be implemented sooner and I suspect the slower "brute force required" methods (like getPointAtLength) will not be implemented as soon because canvas is intended as a fast response element. This is purely my guess. :-//

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is a [pixel manipulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel) element.

SVG is [vector element container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics).

I feel distinction between these two is outside the scope of StackOverflow to dicuss, as it is related to computer art basics, not programming and there is a lot of information available if not in search engines then in WikiPedia. For example one would use pixel-based media for pixel games.